# Android Room database not updating on button click

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, android-room, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow, kotlin-stateflow

I am trying to update values in a room database when a button is clicked in the UI. I am creating an inventory app that allows the user to increase the number of item pieces by one each time a button is clicked. The new number of pieces should be displayed in the UI and the database should be updated.

I have created a method to update the database in the Dao.
I have confirmed that the id/primaryKey of the target row and the model are similar.
I have also tried inserting (with onConflictStategy.REPLACE) instead of updating.
The program works fine and there are no compile-time errors however clicking the button does not update the database. Help me figure out what I am missing. Here is the code.

**Entity**

```kotlin
/**
 * Entity data class represents a single row in the database.
 */

@Entity(tableName = "invent")
data class Item (
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    val id: Int,
    val name: String,
    val category: String,
    val unit: String,
    val pieces: Int,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "piecesBought", defaultValue = "0")
    val piecesBought: Int,
    val price: Int
    )
```

**Dao**

```kotlin
@Dao
interface ItemDao {
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    suspend fun insert(item: Item)

    @Update(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    suspend fun update(item: Item)

    @Delete
    suspend fun delete(item: Item)

    @Query("SELECT * from invent ORDER BY name ASC")
    fun getAllItems(): Flow<List<Item>>

    @Query("SELECT * from invent WHERE id = :id")
    fun getItem(id: Int): Flow<Item?>

    @Query("SELECT * from invent WHERE name like '%'||:name||'%'")
    fun getItemByName(name: String): Flow<List<Item?>>
}
```

**Repository**

```kotlin
class OfflineItemRepository(private val itemDao: ItemDao): ItemRepository {

    override fun getAllItemsStream(): Flow<List<Item>> = itemDao.getAllItems()
    override fun getItemByNameStream(name: String): Flow<List<Item?>> = itemDao.getItemByName(name)

    override fun getItemStream(id: Int): Flow<Item?> = itemDao.getItem(id)

    override suspend fun insertItem(item: Item) = itemDao.insert(item)

    override suspend fun deleteItem(item: Item) = itemDao.delete(item)

    override suspend fun updateItem(item: Item) = itemDao.update(item)
}
```

**viewModel**

The function `increasePiecesBoughtByOne` is called when the button in the UI is clicked.

```kotlin
class ShoppingViewModel (itemRepository: ItemRepository): ViewModel() {

    private val myRepo = itemRepository

    private var _piecesBought = MutableStateFlow("")
    val piecesBought = _piecesBought.asStateFlow()

    /**
     * function to handle adding items to basket on + button click
     * enables the Added to basket button
     */
    fun increasePiecesBoughtByOne(item: Item) {
        // run database operations inside a coroutine.
        viewModelScope.launch {
            withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            when  {
                item.piecesBought < item.pieces -> {
                    myRepo.updateItem(item.copy(piecesBought = (item.piecesBought + 1)))
                    _piecesBought.value = item.piecesBought.toString()
             
                }
            }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**UI**

The value of TextField is given by the `piecesBought` variable from the viewModel as shown below.
I want the piecesBought value to be increased by one each time `onAddItem(item)` is called when the button is clicked but it is not working.

The function `increasePiecesBoughtByOne` is called when the button in the TextField is clicked.
I have confirmed that the function is called when the button is clicked by checking Logcat. However `piecesBought` does not change. Why isn't it changing?

```kotlin
val piecesBought by viewModel.piecesBought.collectAsStateWithLifecycle()

TextField(
                value = piecesBought,
                onValueChange = {
                    onPiecesBoughtChange(it, item)
                                },
                singleLine = true,
                keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(keyboardType = KeyboardType.Number),
                modifier = modifier.weight(1f, fill = true)
            )
            Spacer(modifier.size(ButtonDefaults.IconSpacing))
            Icon(imageVector = Icons.Default.AddCircle,
                contentDescription = "Add item to cart",
                modifier = modifier.clickable {
                    onAddItem(item)
                }
            )
```

**Database**

Database migration from version 1 to version 2 involved creating a new column `piecesBought`

```kotlin
@Database(
    entities = [Item::class],
    version = 2,
    exportSchema = true,
    autoMigrations = [AutoMigration(from = 1, to = 2)]
)

abstract class DukaDatabase: RoomDatabase() {

    abstract fun itemDao(): ItemDao

    companion object {
        @Volatile
        private var Instance: DukaDatabase? = null

        fun getDatabase(context: Context): DukaDatabase {
            // if the Instance is not null, return it, otherwise create a new database instance.
            return Instance ?: synchronized(this) {
                Room.databaseBuilder(context, DukaDatabase::class.java, "duka_database")
                    .createFromAsset("database/inventory_db.db")
                    //.fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
                    .build().also { Instance = it }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show your database provider? It looks like you don't call the same instance of database while you updating records that you used to get the stream.

Comment: @ArekKubiński  I have updated the post with the database instance. I have also used App Inspection to confirm that the application has a single database called 'duka database'. The 'duka_database' has 2 tables. 'inventory' table and 'invent' table. inventory table was used to prepopulate the app. 'invent' table contains the app data.

Comment: From what I see you never actually use flow to update count, in your viewModel you should change piecesBought variable to use getItemStream from your repository instead of updating it manually. Beside this I dont know why your number don't update, looks like something can be wrong when you calling asStateFlow on your already MutableStateFlow in viewModel.

Answer (score 0):

The UI was not updating because I was not using flow to update it as pointed out by [Arek Kubiński](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14744778/arek-kubi%c5%84ski) in the comments. I resolved this by combining 2 flows which would cause a UI update if any of their values changed. The 2 flows are `newPieces` and `_searchText` in the code below. I will focus on only one of the flows which is triggered when the button is clicked (`newPieces`). The other flow (`_searchText`) is tied to a TextField and is updated when the text in the TextField changes. It operates like a searchfield and helps filter `searchList` which is displayed in the UI.

**Combined flow**

Below is the combined flow which updates `searchList` which is the list displayed by the UI. If the `_searchText` variable or `_newPieces` variable changed, it would trigger a call to update `searchList`.

```kotlin
val searchList = _searchText.combine(newPieces) {text, _ ->
        withContext(Dispatchers.IO){ itemRepo.getItemByNameStream(text).first() }
    }.stateIn(
                scope = viewModelScope,
                started = SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed(TIMEOUT_MILLIS),
                initialValue = null
            )
```

**Function to increase count on button click**

This is the function that is called when the button is clicked. As part of this function body I included `_newPieces.emit(item.piecesBought)` that emits a value each time the function is called. This results in a change of the `newPieces` sharedFlow value. This is what causes an update of `searchList` and a change in the UI.

```kotlin
/**
     * function to handle adding items to basket on + button click
     * enables the Added to basket button
     */
    fun increasePiecesBoughtByOne(item: Item) {
        // run database operations inside a coroutine.
        val newPiecesBought: Int = item.piecesBought.inc()
        viewModelScope.launch {
            withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            when  {
                item.piecesBought < item.pieces -> {
                    itemRepo.updateItem(item.copy(piecesBought = newPiecesBought))
                    // emitted value does not matter
                    _newPieces.emit(item.piecesBought)
                }
            }
            }
        }
    }
```

**MutableSharedFlow**

`newPieces.collect{}` collects the new value emitted by `_newPieces.emit(item.piecesBought)` and triggers an update of the UI through a change in `searchList`

```kotlin
/**
     * Using MutableSharedFlow because MutableStateFlow does not emit the same value consecutively
     * MutableSharedFlow does not take an initial value
     */
    private val _newPieces = MutableSharedFlow<Int>(
        replay = 1,
        extraBufferCapacity = 1,
        onBufferOverflow = BufferOverflow.DROP_OLDEST
    )

    private val newPieces = _newPieces.asSharedFlow()
    init {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
                newPieces.collect{
                }
            }
        }

        // providing initial value to be available to combine transformation
        // combine needs values from all the flows (_searchText and newPieces) in order to trigger transformation
        viewModelScope.launch {
            withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {_newPieces.emit(0)}
        }
    }
```